# Jquery Post/AJAX - Does closing window with code affect server script?

Tags: php, jquery

To preface, I know this isn't a great question and it will be hard to explain.

I have a PHP script that takes 5-10 minutes to run. I don't want the user to have to wait for it. If I "trigger" the script using jquery ajax, and then the user navigates away from that page or closes the browser (and doesn't wait for the response (if any) which will come much later), will the script still execute fully (assuming there are no errors etc)

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`ignore_user_abort(true)`](http://php.net/manual/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and you'll be fine.

Comment: PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see [flush()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

Comment: if you close the window, user (you) wont get the reponse. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the server receives the AJAX Request along with the data, it would process it as usual, even if you close the page or the window. If you close the browser window before the server receives the AJAX Request, the processing it not going to happen.

Furthermore, if the AJAX Request is returning any kind of data or displaying messages, it is advised that you leave the window open, so that there is some "Listening" page to the Server's Request Response.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script you could call the `ignore_user_abort(true)` function which would cause the script to run regardless of the user closing the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line if you have access to one:

```
php /loc/to/file.php
```

This does not have a timeout and might be faster than port:80 (a browser calling an phpfile)

Or call the main phpfile in another file via a php's [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
<?php
exec("php /loc/to/file.php > /loc/to/result.txt");
?>
```

You might want to use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
The dir of results.txt and the file itself need to be writable.
The 'greater than' sign writes the output of the phpfile to `result.txt`. If the php would echo `123`, that would be the contents of result.txt

---

5 to 10 minutes is a **very** long time, you might want to check your code for improvements. If you are using a database, add indice (an index)  on columns u use allot, that ccan save huge amounts of tim

Comment: if I use the php exec code you wrote above, and then I close the browser window, what happens? why is that better than using jquery to call the script?

Comment: @Martijn :  Good to know. But where is this answer related to OP's question ? In short : `Runs a script on if user close the browser ?`

Comment: The file will run in the background, therefor can not be stopped by the user leaving. The original question was answered in the comments